# FancyBox 2 Background Issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to use fancybox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to show an image automatically on my page, but the background (greyed-out) portion is not working.  Any ideas?

See example at http://www.southshoreopera.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that if you open fancybox programmatically BEFORE the DOM is ready, somehow the overlay is not appended to the `body` element.

This :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  // API options
});
$(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
</script>
```

... will trigger fancybox on page load WITHOUT an overlay (a manual `click` to the link thereafter won't reproduce the issue though)

You should wrap at least the `.trigger()` method inside the `.ready()` method like :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
  // API options
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".fancybox").eq(0).trigger('click');
});
</script>
```

You can leave the fancybox init outside the `.ready()` method **IF** you are initializing it at the bottom of the page otherwise you should also move it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded and correctly placed the fancybox_overlay.png?

The background is created through the use of an image, so if the .png file is not at the correct path being called, it will not appear. I believe it needs to be in the same folder as the .css file.

**EDIT:**

Looking closer at the CSS file you find this:

```
.fancybox-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: none;
    z-index: 8010;
    background: url('fancybox_overlay.png');
}
```

You can either place the overlay.png file in the CSS folder, or change the path of the url such that it finds the image. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't think there is an issue with the `fancybox_overlay.png` file since the close and navigation arrows show up properly (also included in the `fancybox_overlay.png` file http://www.southshoreopera.org/fancybox/source/fancybox_sprite.png)