# Fancybox Overlay doesn't show when simulating click

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I have a fancy set up at the top of document.ready that looks like this:

```
$('.fancyBox').fancybox({
            'type': 'iframe',
            'closeBtn': false,
            'overlayShow' : true
        });
```

Afterwards I'm checking a value on the page and simulating a click fi its true

```
            if ($('#fromLogin').val() == "True") {
            $('a#fancyLink').trigger('click');
        }
```

Everything works fine but except the overlay doesn't show up.  When I click the link manually it works fine though.  What could I be missing?

EDIT:  The relevant HTML posted below for the parent.

```
<input type="hidden" id="fromLogin" value= "@ViewBag.FromLogin" />
<a href="../Account/AccountOverview" id="fancyLink" class="fancyBox" style="display: block;">Click</a>

<div id="account_settings">
@Html.ActionLink("Update Account Settings", "Manage", "Account")
</div>
<div id="main_wide"> .... </div>
```

Comment: I am guessing you have this issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/18326028/1055987

Comment: possible duplicate of [FancyBox 2 Background Issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18323969/fancybox-2-background-issue)

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping the part of your code that triggers the click like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
   if ($('#fromLogin').val() == "True") {
      $('a#fancyLink').trigger('click');
   }
});
```